# How to loop through pages automatically with javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, onload-event

I'd like to loop through 5 pages at a certain time interval. The below code only works to loop through all pages once. How could I make it so that it loops through those 5 pages infinitely instead of just running just once?

HTML

```
<div class="page">Page 2 Content</div>
<div class="page">Page 3 Content</div>
<div class="page">Page 4 Content</div>
<div class="page">Page 5 Content</div>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var TIME_PER_PAGE = 2000;
    var pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
    var numPages = pages ? pages.length : 0;
    var i = -1;

    function nextPage() {
        if (i >= 0)
            pages[i].classList.remove('currentPage');
        i++;
        pages[i].classList.add('currentPage');
        if (i < numPages - 1)
          setTimeout(nextPage, TIME_PER_PAGE);
    }

    nextPage();
}
```

Comment: Use *i % numPages*. Then you will be able to use *i* variable infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code snippet and the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u62bqb62/1/

```
function nextPage() {
    if (i >= 0)
        $(pages[i]).removeClass('currentPage');

    i = ++i % numPages;

    $(pages[i]).addClass('currentPage');

    setTimeout(nextPage, TIME_PER_PAGE);
}
```